# How to create LootBox System like videogames

Tags: java, inheritance, system

I want to practice java creating a LootBox Open System. I just tried this.

-Creating an Interface called Tier.
-Creating UltimateTier,PremiumTier,StandardTier classes that implements Tier Interface.
-Creating classes like Gold that extends UltimateTier,Titanium extends UltimateTier, Silver extends PremiumTier, etc.

Then I use org.reflections to find  classes that inherits from another to create chances to get rare items like gold with this code

```
Tier[] tierItem = new Tier[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         int itemQuality = (int)(1 + Math.random()* 10);

        int itemQuality = 1;
        if (itemQuality == 1) {
            tierItem[i] = new UltimateItemTier().getItem();
        }
        if (itemQuality >= 2 && itemQuality <= 4) {
            tierItem[i] = new PremiumItemTier();

        }
        if (itemQuality >= 5) {
            tierItem[i] = new StandardItemTier();
        }
    }

    return tierItem;
```

It returns me a list of 3 TIERITEMS, but I need to choose randomly 1 of those items for according to each tier on the list.

for example, if there is 10 PremiumItems and when I open the StandarBox, the list return "PremiumTier", "PremiumTier" , "StandardTier", the code must select any random item that inherits or match that Tier.

So list must return ( for example ) "Silver(PremiumTier), PremiumMetal(PremiumTier), Wood(StandardTier)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @akuzminykh I don't know how to return the list of items choosed randomly from each tier, if I opened the box, it shows "PremiumTier", "PremiumTier" , "UltimateTier" ( for example ), but I cannot think a way to select items ramdomly with that tier ( I don't want to use DB or another tools, just java )

Comment: If you like, please post all the code that declares/defines all this classes. Also please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help people to understand your question and find the error.